# formvalidations.io and conditional validation

Tags: bootstrap-modal, formvalidation-plugin

I have 10 fields on my bootstrap form, 5 of them needs to be validated when "Save as draft" button is clicked and all 10 of them must be validated when "Submit" button is clicked.

I don't see any example to accomplish the same.

Any examples?

Answer (score 1):

have you tried disabling validation on fields when you click the other button...

```
function chechUserValidation() {

    $('#create_loan_form')
        .formValidation('enableFieldValidators', 'field1', false)
        .formValidation('enableFieldValidators', 'field2', false)
        .formValidation('enableFieldValidators', 'field3', false)
 .......
```

Then call the function on click for the second  button